# How can I check multiple duplicates in one array? [ReadyJava]

Tags: java, arrays, loops, integer

This program receives 100 inputs and then outputs the lowest value. I need help checking all duplicated values inputted.

Example with 5 inputs:
5,1,1,5,4

The smallest value: 1

The amount of duplicated values: 4

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
public class ArrayNumbers
{
static Console c;           

public static void main (String[] args)
 {
    c = new Console ();
    int number[] = new int [100], i = 1, output = 0;
    c.print ("Enter number #1:");
    number [0] = c.readInt ();
    output = number [0];

    for (int count = 0 ; count < 99 ; count++)
    {
        c.print ("Enter number #" + (count + 2)+ ":");
        number [i] = c.readInt ();
        if (number [i] < output)
        {
            output = number [i];
        }
        i++;
    }
c.print(output);
 } // main method
} // ArrayNumbers class
```

Comment: Add each number you read in to a `HashSet`, because it doesn't let you add duplicates. Then subtract the size of the set from the total number of integers. This will give you the number of duplicates.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson I was just writing an answer, but yours is better, please make an answer

Comment: @ScaryWombat Done.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using map. Please find below code for the same:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinAndDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number, totalDupCount=0;
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        //Prepare map with duplicate count for each number
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            number=stdin.nextInt();
            if(map.containsKey(number)){
                map.put(number, ((Integer)map.get(number)+1));
            }else{
                map.put(number, 1);
            }
        }

         for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                int numberCount= entry.getValue();
                if (numberCount> 1) {
                    totalDupCount+= numberCount;
                }
            }

        System.out.println(totalDupCount);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: don't forget `stdin.close();`

Comment: You just copied my answer but pasted it into a single method and renamed some things... --- Also this example only works for 5 inputs. The question is meant to be for 100.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the logic to perform your `duplicate count` in O(n) time and O(1) extra space.

try this

```
// Function to find counts of all elements present in
// arr[0..n-1]. The array elements must be range from
// 1 to n
// Traverse all array elements
int[] arr = {5,1,1,5,4};
int i = 0,n=arr.length;
int totalDupCount = 0;
while (i < n) {
    // If this element is already processed,
    // then nothing to do
    if (arr[i] <= 0) {
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    // Find index corresponding to this element

    int elementIndex = arr[i] - 1;

    // If the elementIndex has an element that is not
    // processed yet, then first store that element
    // to arr[i] so that we don't loose anything.
    if (arr[elementIndex] > 0) {
        arr[i] = arr[elementIndex];

        // After storing arr[elementIndex], change it
        // to store initial count of 'arr[i]'
        arr[elementIndex] = -1;
    } else {
        // If this is NOT first occurrence of arr[i],
        // then increment its count.
        arr[elementIndex]--;

        // And initialize arr[i] as 0 means the element
        // 'i+1' is not seen so far
        arr[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
}

System.out.println("Below are counts of all elements");
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if(Math.abs(arr[j]) >= 2){
            System.out.println(j + 1 + "->" + Math.abs(arr[j]));
            totalDupCount +=Math.abs(arr[j]);
        }
}
System.out.println("Total Duplicate Count in Array is : "+totalDupCount);
```

}

Output

```
Below are counts of all elements
1->2
5->2
Total Duplicate Count in Array is : 4
```

Answer (score 0):

*(This post is slightly uglier than my first approach, but it solves the poster's question the way they'd like it to. I have decided to put it as a separate answer.)*

> If you want to count the number of duplicated numbers multiple times
>   depending on how often they show up, you can do it with a
>   [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

#### The Approach

- Create a HashMap to count how often each number appears.
- When reading input, increment the occurrences of that number.
- To find the number of "duplicates", iterate through the HashMap and sum all of the occurrences which happen more than once.

#### Example

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DuplicateCounter {

    static int[] numbers = new int[100];
    static HashMap<Integer, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readInput();
        int duplicates = countDuplicates();
        System.out.printf("%d numbers appeared multiple times.\n", duplicates);
    }

    public static void readInput() {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int number = stdin.nextInt();
            numbers[i] = number;
            incrementCount(number);
        }
        stdin.close();
    }

    public static int countDuplicates() {
        int duplicates = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : occurrences.entrySet()) {
            int numOfOccurrences = entry.getValue();
            if (numOfOccurrences > 1) {
                duplicates += numOfOccurrences;
            }
        }
        return duplicates;
    }

    public static void incrementCount(int number) {
        if (occurrences.get(number) != null) {
            int previous = occurrences.get(number);
            occurrences.put(number, previous + 1);
        } else {
            occurrences.put(number, 1);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: why do you still have `int[] numbers` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm assuming they want to store the input in some sort of order somewhere. It can be removed if you think it's a problem.